# Firing a Canon Speedlite 430 EX III-RT in manual wirelessly

Tags: hotshoe-flash, wireless-flash, manual-mode

Is it possible to fire my 430EX III-RT flash in manual as a slave wirelessly?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to fire my 430EX III-RT flash in manual as a slave wirelessly?

**Yes.** See the information starting on page 62 of [the Canon 430EX III-RT manual](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/0/0300019910/01/sl430exiii-rt-im-en.pdf)(PDF). You can trigger your flash while it's in manual mode, and you can even trigger several flashes that are each in different modes. You can trigger the flash using the radio transmission system, or you can do it using the optical transmission system (see page 78). Basically, your choice of flash mode (ETTL, M, etc.) is independent of your choice of how to trigger the flash.

Perhaps it should be said, though, that however you decide to trigger your flash, you'll need a device that's able to act as a master unit, whether that's a ST-E3-RT, another flash that can work as a radio master (i.e. a 600 EX-RT or 600 EX II-RT), or one of the options for an optical master.

Answer (score 1):

Any triggering system that can trigger your 430EX III-RT off camera in E-TTL mode can also be set to control it manually off camera.

The 430EX III-RT has both an *optical* receiver and a Canon RT *radio* receiver. The *optical* receiver can be controlled by any flash that is a Canon *optical* Master flash (580EX II, Yongnuo YN568EX II, etc.), or a near infrared *optical* controller (ST-E2 or third party clone). The RT *radio* receiver can be controlled by any *radio* controller in Canon's RT system such as the ST-E3-RT (or third party clone such as the YN-E3-RT), or a *radio* Master flash such as the 600EX-RT (or clone like the YN600EX-RT or YN600EX-RT II).

Depending upon what model camera you are using, you may be able to control the 430EX III-RT *optically* using the camera's pop-up flash *if* the flash is a Canon *optical* Master.

- The first Rebel/xx0D model to include this feature was the Rebel T3i/600D.
- The first x0D model with a pop-up flash that is a Master flash was the 60D.
- The original 7D also has a Master pop-up flash.

In each case, subsequent models in the three product lines listed above have continued to have this capability. (The 1D, 5D, and 6D series don't have built in flashes at all - for those you'll need an external controller or Master flash mounted on the hot shoe.)

You can also use any radio trigger set (a transmitter on the camera and a receiver attached to the foot of the flash) that is compatible with Canon's E-TTL system, such as the YN622C system. A YN622C-TX on the camera and a YN622C II receiver on the flash would allow you both E-TTL (including HSS, Multi flash, etc) as well as manual control.

Comment: Thank you both for your considerate and in- depth answers. I have a 60D and using a ST-E3-RT to fire my 430ex III-RT. My problem is not being able to get my flash out of ETTL to put into manual when in slave using radio transmission.

Comment: After playing some more, and after hitting the test button on my flash it switched over to Manual. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, when you make changes via the camera menu, you must do a shutter half press (or press the transmitter's 'test' button) to make the changes take effect from the camera. The flash should be set to 'neutral' settings before starting: +/- 0 FEC in E-TTL mode, 'Auto" zoom, 1/1 (full) manual power, etc.If a non-neutral setting is selected via the flash's control panel the wireless master will sometimes not be able to change that setting.